# Perl Script not locating File via its set path

Tags: sql-server, perl, cgi

I am working on a reporting tool called MARS (Multi Access Reporting Service). This is a tool which reads reports via a SQL server. We have a local machine test environment setup which has everything running fine but when we upload onto the Windows Server 2008 it seems to not want to locate a "required" file. We are running Perl(v5.14.2) on the server and an older version on the desktop/local.

the error i am receieving is:
***HTTP Error 502.2 - Bad Gateway
The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers. The headers it did return are "Can't locate jsdb.pl in @INC (@INC contains: /Inetpub/Scripts /Inetpub/Scripts/Security c:/Perl/site/lib c:/Perl/lib .) at \gl-0185-nas07p\MCL_Dev_MPN_GL\Green_App\MARS\Scripts\Security\security.pl line 7. ".***

Here is the header on the Security.pl file which clearly has the set path and file in it:

```
use CGI qw/:standard *table start_ul/;
use Date::Calc;
use Win32::ODBC;
use POSIX qw(floor);

###
use lib "/Inetpub/Scripts/Security";
require "jsdb.pl";
###
require "javascript.pl";
require "SecurityUtils.pl";
use lib "/Inetpub/Scripts";
require "webpageutils.pl";
```

Within the JSDB file is the code for the "Profiles" tab which is used to setup and modify users of the system.

Any help is really appreciated as we cannot seem to get our heads around it.

Comment: The error includes the @INC list.  Are you sure the user that the script runs under has read rights on that directory?  if you're using IIS in Windows 8, the user would be `IUSR`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. I am currently logged in as an Admin for the application and this is the error it shows.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be insensitive to case sensitivity, i.e. in the file it is listed as jsdb.pl and in your question you identify it as JSDB. Also, the error message identifies the offending file as security.pl, but your question calls it Security.pl. Perl is case sensitive. Is it possible this could be a factor, e.g. the jsdb.pl file is actually named JSDB.pl?

Answer (score 0):

Where is `jsdb.pl`? From your source file I would guess it's in `/Inetpub/Scripts/Security` which doesn't look like a Windows path to me.

At a guess, only `C:/Perl/site/lib` and  `C:/Perl/lib` exist on your Windows Server machine, and the other paths are either different on that machine or you simply have no access to `jsdb.pl` from there

Also, you don't seem to be using `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of your code, and your method of using libraries by `require 'library.pl'` could be very much better

Comment: Thanks guys i located the problem to be that the file where not stored under Inetpub. Inetpud is where they were stored on our local test environment but on the server the directory changed. I have made the changes and it works fine now.